# How would I detect a click within an area that has a jQuery plugin already listening for clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-bar-rating

I'm using the [jQuery Bar Rating Plugin](http://netboy.pl/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples). Everything with the plugin works fine (it effectively turns a select list into a series of clickable images) , but I want to 'reveal' a hidden field elsewhere on the page when the user selects something from the select-list that the plugin is controlling.

**To be explicit about what I'm attempting to do**:

When a user updates the rating shown by `Bar Rating` I want to reveal a save button to confirm the changes.  If the user has not yet changed the rating, I don't want the save button to be showing.

**Attempt 1**:

```
$('#my-div).click ->
  $('#div-to-be-revealed').toggleClass('invisible')
```

But the code never fires because the plugin is watching the children of the div (the actual things that would be clicked) and it does something with 'click' before this code ever gets a chance to run.

**Attempt 2**:

```
$("#my-div").bind "DOMSubtreeModified", ->
  $('#div-to-be-revealed').toggleClass('invisible')
```

The above code fires whenever the div modified by the `Bar Rating` plugin is modified.  The problem is, the event is triggered several times during the initial loading of the page (because the plugin is updating elements) and is triggered when my mouse hovers over elements of the div that the plugin modifies on hover.

Without modifying the plugin's code, how would I detect when a user has updated a value in the 'select list' managed by the `Bar Rating` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the callback methods:

[from the docs](http://netboy.pl/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/)

> Callbacks
>
> onSelect:function(value, text) Fired when a rating is selected.
>
> onClear:function(value, text) Fired when a rating is cleared.
>
> onDestroy:function(value, text) Fired when a rating is destroyed.

I do believe you will use: `onSelect` callback.

```
$('#example-e').barrating('show', {
        onSelect:function(value, text) {
        //your code goes here.
        $('#div-to-be-revealed').toggleClass('invisible')
        alert('Selected rating: ' + value);
    }
});
```